# Acer Aspire One

Tags: acer, aspire

So about a year back I dual booted my Aspire one with a Linix OS I Liked the OS but it was a little to advanced for my undoubtedly tiny graphics card. Looking at other options I found the OS that I have Currently which is Ubuntu 0.140.1 Recently my Computer told me that I needed to upgrade to 0.140.2. My issue is that when ever I go to do it that the system warns me that my tiny Graphics card cant support this new version. now to my questions: Is there an Ubuntu or Linix OS that I can get that will not have this issue at some point? What is it? How can I get it?

Comment: Consider a more light weight distro: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Linux_distribution ... I enjoy "crunchbang" but there are many to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

If your system is low end then you can use lubuntu which is made for low end pc and laptop.It is similar to ubuntu in functionality.You can download iso from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) .

Answer (score 0):

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit on my Acer Aspire One ZG5, which is a 1.5gb RAM netbook. Very slow compared to smartphones and tablets now, but it is still functional. I installed from USB, since the ZG5 has no CD/DVD.
It takes time to open applications. It can still stream video from Netflix, but lags from Youtube due to the ads. I love using this computer, even though my tablet and smartphone are faster.

So, to answer your question, you should be able to run Ubuntu 14.04 on your Acer Aspire. Download the Ubuntu version that will boot from a USB and then install when you run it the first time. Good luck.